# How can I get a image from Firebase storage with the file name I stored in the database?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I stored a image in firebase storage and image path in Firestore, how can I get that specific image using the path saved in Firestore?

```
  getImagePath() async {
    var document = await firestoreInstance
        .collection("products")
        .document(widget.productId)
        .get();

    String path = document["filePath"];
    setState(() {
      filePath = path;
    });
  }
```

I got the filename from Firestore like this, how can I get the image by using this file name?

Comment: what does file path looks like can you comment?

Comment: "image_picker4011381564582645700.jpg" like this

Comment: When you are uploading the image to firebase you should get the download link at that time and store it.

Answer (score 2):

I could give you an idea.
Since you have commented that your `filePath` looks like this **image_picker4011381564582645700.jpg**, then you must be storing only the file names. Then, you can something like this with the help of [firebase_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_storage)

```
String getStorageUrl(String fileName) async {
   
   String url = "";
   StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("folder/$fileName");
   url = await storageReference.getDownloadURL();
   return url;
}
```

Call the function, where you want it. Or in your case,

```
getImagePath() async {
  var document = await firestoreInstance
      .collection("products")
      .document(widget.productId)
      .get();

  String path = await getStorageUrl(document["filePath"]);
  setState(() {
    filePath = path;
  });
}
```

You could then use that URL in an `Image.network()` to display it, or if you have other plans with it, you can go for [flutter_downloader](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader). 
Make sure, you are changing the function with the correct folder name. Hope that suits your case.

> **Tip:** It is better to store the full URL to the database, instead of just saving the file name.

Comment: thank you bro it's working, but it takes too long to load

Comment: Yeah! That depends on your file size and internet speed.That's why if you could store entire `downloadURL` in the database, `.getDownloadURL()`'s time can be saved.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use FirebaseImage widget

```
         CircleAvatar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,   
        backgroundImage:
   FirebaseImage('gs://yourapp=67791.appspot.com/images/cPW7zkbCpYQT2II7JqEOcUK5rOm2.png'),
                     )
```

Answer (score 0):

`NetworkImage()` and `Image.network()` directly fetch image from given Firebase image storage

```
//To set image on background

CircleAvatar(
  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,foregroundColor:Colors.blueAccent,
  radius:16,
  backgroundImage:NetworkImage(filepath),
  child: FlatButton(
    onPressed: (){
      print("button pressed");},
    ),
  ),

//within child 

Container(
   child:Image.network(filepath),
);
```